# Missing Odd Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

A set of whole numbers (0-) will be given separated by a space. Some numbers will be missing between certain numbers in the set. Your job is to find the missing odd numbers between them.

### Conditions

1. The input will be a one line string.
2. Your code must left out a variable for inserting the input case
   string.
3. The output should be a **string** containing all the missing odd
   numbers in the set of numbers given as input.
4. **The numbers of the output must be separated by a comma - `,`**.
5. No extra characters should be included in the output.
6. If there are no odd numbers missing, the code should print out
   `null` or a blank line.

Here are some sample inputs and outputs according to its order :

### Input

```
4 6 8 10
5 15 18 21 26
2 15 6
1 20
1 3 5 7 9
```

### Output

```
5,7,9
7,9,11,13,17,19,23,25
3,5,7,9,11,13
3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19
null
```

The winner will be decided by the Code length.

**The calculation of code length won't include the variable that is left for the test case.**

Comment: @ProgramFOX PHP codes won't be shorter. It's hard to make a short code in PHP that solves the problem. This question is to promote PHP coding. Since codegolf discourages questions of single languages, other language answers are being accepted. I made the PHP need, because other language codes can be shorter. But it's hard to make it in PHP.

Comment: Seems awfully unfair to state that you'll be awarding the win to PHP, even if it's longer than the shortest not-PHP solution.

Comment: Removed arbitrary language requirement; challenges here are generally language-agnostic unless a very good reason exists to limit or otherwise suppress other languages.

Comment: @KyleKanos OK, so can I make this problem only in PHP without getting the question closed ?

Comment: Again, why *must* your answer be in PHP? This is beginning to sound like a homework problem....

Comment: @KyleKanos No it's not. OK, every language it is

Comment: Why the required string case parameter? the input is only numbers

Comment: @Einacio To easily give the input numbers separated by the whitespace. No, the variable won't be counted for choosing the winner.

Comment: "Your code must left out a variable for inserting the input case string." — I don't understand what this means.

Comment: I infer from the test cases that the intention is that the order of the input numbers is irrelevant, and that the output numbers should be greater than the minimum of the input and less than the maximum of the input. If this is the intention, it would be helpful to make it explicit.

Comment: It's unclear from test case 3 whether the 6 is used or discarded as bad input.  Since the 6 is the only number that's out of order, it's kind of a game changer.

Comment: @James Even if the numbers in the set are out of order like `5 9 3`, the code should find the missing odd numbers. The conditions never said that the numbers given will be in order.

Comment: Generally, [Strict IO formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/62574) are discouraged. I see no reason why this challenge should require String input and the numbers separated by commas in the output. Some languages don't have the concept of Strings or variables, and a few automatically print a space after every number. These strict requirements detract from an otherwise pretty good challenge IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### GolfScript (20 chars)

```
~]$),\(),+-{1&},','*
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyBUZXN0IGZyYW1ld29yawo7JzQgNiA4IDEwCjUgMTUgMTggMjEgMjYKMiAxNSA2CjEgMjAKMSAzIDUgNyA5J24vewoKIyBQcm9ncmFtCgp%2BXSQpLFwoKSwrLXsxJn0sJywnKgoKIyBNb3JlIHRlc3QgZnJhbWV3b3JrCnB1dHN9Lw%3D%3D)

Dissection:

```
~]$   # Eval the string, wrap the resulting integers in an array, sort
),    # Extract the max and make an array A of 0 to max-1 inclusive
\(),  # Extract the min and make an array B of 0 to min inclusive
+-    # Combine B with the remaining numbers from the input and remove them from A
{1&}, # Filter A to odd numbers
','*  # Comma-separate
```

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby, 74

```
s="insert your numbers here" # this line not counted per the rules
n=s.split.map &:to_i
puts (n.min..n.max).select{|x|x%2==1&&!n.index(x)}*?,
```

Output is identical to examples in question except that it outputs a blank line for no numbers found.

Comment: The output must be a string (not array) of missing odd numbers separated by comma `,`. No extra chars like `[` are allowed.

Comment: @Subin Ok, fixed. (You can't really output anything that's not a string, though; I'm having trouble understanding what that rule means.)

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 82 chars

```
N=map(int,I.split())
R=','.join(`x`for x in range(min(N)|1,max(N),2)if x not in N)
```

Set `I` to your input string, `R` is the output string.

Comment: `+1` for `min(N)|1` finding first odd number in range

Comment: You can still improve the character count. As the question doesn't require the arguments to be in order you could do `','.join(\`x\`for x in set(range(min(N)|1,max(N),2))-set(N))`

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, <s>92</s> <s>79</s> 72 chars

```
x=args; //Input does not count
x=x*.toInteger();print((x.min()..x.max()).minus(x).grep{it%2}.join(","))
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 205 characters: 222 (total count) - 17 (total length of variable)

```c#
namespace System.Linq{class A{static void Main(){var a="4 6 8 10";var b=a.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse);Console.WriteLine(String.Join<int>(",",Enumerable.Range(b.Min(),b.Max()-b.Min()).Where(x=>x%2==1&&!b.Contains(x))));}}}
```

**Ungolfed code:**

```c#
namespace System.Linq
{
    class A
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var a = "4 6 8 10";
            var b = a.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join<int>(",", Enumerable.Range(b.Min(), b.Max() - b.Min()).Where(x => x % 2 == 1 && !b.Contains(x))));
        }
    }
}
```

How it works: first, it splits the input string and parses each number into an integer. Then, it creates a range from the minimum occuring integer to the maximum and it takes all odd integers which do not occur in the input string.

Comment: I wrote the C# solution to this and was about to post it until I realized we came up with the exact same solution....

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 106

```
<?
$a = '4 6 8 10';
$a=split(' ',$a);foreach(range(min($a),max($a))as$i)if($i%2&&!in_array($i,$a))$d[]=$i;echo join(',',$d);
```

i'm not sure about what to discount from the char count, so i just discounted the line with the declaration

Comment: If set of numbers that doesn't have missing odd numbers, the code produces a warning : https://eval.in/157049 which according to the conditions are not allowed.

Comment: that condition is new...

Comment: @Subin fixed the warnings

Comment: Nice. I made it more complicated than necessary, as usual. :)

Answer (score 2):

## ised, 23 characters (16 code + 7 flags)

This is what [ised](http://ised.sourceforge.net/) is best at!

```
ised --d, --l input.dat 'O[min$1max$1]\$1'
```

Not counting the name of the file (which could be replaced by `-` for standard input), this clocks in at 23 characters plus program name plus punctuation needed for spacing the command line arguments. The actual code is just `O[min$1max$1]\$1`.

Explanation: `--d,` sets the output delimiter. `--l <file>` signifies that the following code is applied to each line. `$1` represents the current line. The min and max elements are used to initialize the sequence constructor `[]`. `O` selects the odd numbers. `\$1` is the set-wise *without* operator, which removes the already given numbers from the generated sequence.

Please clarify how the characters should be counted. Does the name `ised` of the command count or not?

Comment: Input is not sorted (look at the examples)

Comment: Got it. Fixed...

Comment: I think the standard scoring for this would be 23: 16 for the program and 7 for the flags `--d, --l`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 110 chars

```
$a=split(' ',$i);echo join(',',array_filter(array_diff(range(min($a),max($a)),$a),function($n){return$n&1;}));
```

More readable version:

```
$a = split(' ', $i);
echo join(',',
    array_filter(
        array_diff(
            range(min($a), max($a)),
            $a
        ),
        function($n) {
            return $n & 1;
        }
    )
);
```

This basically creates an array of all the numbers within the range and uses a bitwise `$n & 1` to check if the number is even or odd.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/157285)

Comment: You can save 2 characters by replacing `min($a)` with `$a[0]`, as the first number has to be the smallest.

Comment: @MrLore [Order of the input is not guaranteed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28801/missing-odd-numbers/28813#comment62881_28801).

Comment: @nderscore: Oh, I hadn't noticed that. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 20

```
JSrz7j\,-f%T2rhJeJJ
```

`J` is the list of integers, sorted. `rhJeJ` gives all of the possible integers between the min and max of the input. `f%T2` filters out the even numbers. `-_J` filters out the original elements of J. `j\,` joins the resultant list on commas, and the string is automatically printed.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of @Kevin Cruijssen's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187447/99035):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes (flexible I/O)

```
₌htṡF'∷
```

```
₌ht      # push head and tail of input
   ṡ     # range(a, b + 1)
    F    # filter by elements not in input
     '∷  # filter by odds
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%8Cht%E1%B9%A1F%27%E2%88%B7&inputs=%5B4%2C%207%5D&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes (exact I/O)

```
⌈vI:₌htṡF'∷;\,j
```

Same principles, but `⌈vI:` takes input as a space separated list, and `\,j` formats the list to be comma separated.

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%88vI%3A%E2%82%8Cht%E1%B9%A1F%27%E2%88%B7%3B%5C%2Cj&inputs=%604%20100%60&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (E6) 100 <s>110</s>

Edit: join in output is unnecessary (stolen from nderscore but too obvious)
Edit2: see comments
Edit3: fixed bug, skip min if odd
Edit4: teamwork ... (loop for every number, then inside loop skip even ones)

```
t='13 15 20 2'; /* Not counted */
l=t.split(' ').sort((a,b)=>b-a);for(n=l.pop(o=[]);++n<l[0];)n%2&!l.some(x=>x==n)&&o.push(n);alert(o)
```

Comment: Our answers have ended up being the same, so I removed mine. You beat me by a few minutes haha.

Comment: -1 byte: move `o=[]` inside of `pop()`

Comment: Why do you have to skip the min value? You're already checking if the value isn't in `l` before adding it to your output array.

Comment: I check all the numbers using 'l', but I get the min with pop(), so it's not there anymore. The relation between min and initial n is 2-->3, 3-->5, 4-->5 and so on

Comment: Makes sense now. Bring it back to 100: `l=t.split(' ').sort((a,b)=>b-a);for(n=l.pop(o=[]);++n<l[0];)n%2&!l.some(x=>x==n)&&o.push(n);alert(o)`

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, <s>51</s> 40 characters

```
' '/{~}/]$:a),\(,\;-{.2%\a?-1=&},{','}/;
```

Input should be on STDIN. [Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycyIDE1IDYnCgonICcve359L10kOmEpLFwoLFw7LXsuMiVcYT8tMT0mfSx7JywnfS87)

If input on STDIN is not allowed, then changing it so it allows variables only adds 1 character.

Ungolfed code with explanation:

```
' '/ # split input string
{~}/ # convert all strings into integers
]$   # put integers into an array and sort it
:a   # put array into variable a
)    # take last element from array
,    # create an array from 0 to the integer obtained from previous command
\    # swap new array and first array, first array is now on top
(    # take first element from first array
,    # create an array from 0 to the integer obtained from previous command
\;   # swap newest array and first array, and remove first array
-    # remove elements from second array if they also occur in third (newest) array
{    # this block will be used to process elements in the array
  .   # duplicate current item twice
  2%   # obtain the remainder when dividing it by 2
  \    # swap remainder and one of the duplicates
  a?   # obtain the index of the current item in the first array which is stored in variable a
  -1=  # check if index is -1 (the item is not found)
  &  # returns 1 if it is a missing odd number
},   # filter contents of array, only keep missing odd numbers
{','}/;  # separate results with commas
```

Comment: `array block ,` as `filter` is very useful here.

Comment: Next you'll be posting pages full of 1's and 0's. lol :) +1

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (*ES6*) - 85

Edit: Undeleted, as I found a solution that's different enough from edc65's to justify it's own answer.

```javascript
i='13 15 20 2' // input is not part of byte count
o=[];i.split(' ').sort((a,b)=>a-b).sort((a,b)=>{for(;++a<b;)a%2&&o.push(a)});alert(o)
```

Ungolfed / Commented:

```javascript
o=[];               // array for output
i.split(' ').       // split input by spaces
  sort((a,b)=>a-b). // sort by numeric order
  sort((a,b)=>{     // abuse sort as a way to run a function on every pair of neighboring 
                    // values the array in order
    for(;++a<b;)    // loop from a+1 to b-1 
      if(a%2)       // if odd
        o.push(a)   // push to array
  });               // the sort function returns nothing, so the order of the array is 
                    // unchanged and no pair is compared twice
alert(o)            // the array is cast to a string, which is comma separated by default
```

Answer (score 1):

## J - 42 char

```
}.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:4 6 8 10
```

I exclude from the character count the `=:4 6 8 10` portion, but I include the `n` because that's part of the rest of the code—assignments can have return values in J.

Explained by explosion:

```
}.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:4 6 8 10  NB. missing odd numbers
                                         n=:4 6 8 10  NB. input assigned to n
                                      >./n            NB. maximum of n
                                  i.1+                NB. integers from 0 to max(n) incl.
                          (<./n)                      NB. minimum of n
                                }.                    NB. drop first min(n) values
                       l=.                            NB. assign this to l
                     2|                               NB. modulo 2: 0 for evens, 1 for odds
                  l#~                                 NB. keep the odd numbers from l
              n-.~                                    NB. discard numbers already in n
   (      )&.>                                        NB. for each number:
        ":                                            NB.   convert to string
    ',',                                              NB.   and prepend a comma
  ;                                                   NB. run together all results
}.                                                    NB. remove leading comma
```

Example usage:

```
   }.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:4 6 8 10
5,7,9
   }.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:5 15 18 21 26
7,9,11,13,17,19,23,25
   }.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:2 15 6
3,5,7,9,11,13
   }.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:1 20
3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19
   }.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:1 3 5 7 9    NB. blank line

   # }.;(',',":)&.>n-.~l#~2|l=.(<./n)}.i.1+>./n=:1 3 5 7 9  NB. see? length is 0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>101</s> <s>99</s> <s>95</s> <s>91</s> <s>78</s> 58 chars

```
$a=$args #input doesn't count
$a=$a|sort;($a[0]..$a[-1]|?{$_%2-and!($a-like$_)})-join','
```

It outputs the same results as the example, and new line if there are no odd numbers missing.

Ungolfed code:

```
#input doesn't count
$a=$args 
# Sort input array
$a=$a | sort;
# Loop from numbers starting at first (min) and ending at last (max) elements of array
($a[0] .. $a[-1] | ?{
    # Ouptup if element is even and is not contained in original input array
    $_ % 2 -and !($a -like $_
# Print output elements joined by ","
})-join','
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 118 chars

```
// $n='4 6 8 11 14';
$o=[];$a=explode(' ',$n);foreach(range(min($a),max($a))as$b)if($b%2!=0&&!in_array($b,$a))$o[]=$b;echo implode(',',$o);
```

Expanded...

```
// Empty array to hold the output
$o = [];

// Put each number in a zero indexed array
$a = explode(' ', $n);

// Iterate through each number between the smallest number and the largest number, inclusive
foreach(range(min($a), max($a)) as $b) {

    // If the number is not even and it's not one of the numbers in the input,
    // then add it to the output array
    if ($b % 2 != 0 && !in_array($b, $a)) {
        $o[] = $b;
    }
}

// Glue the numbers in the output array together with a comma
echo implode(',', $o);
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works exactly?

Comment: @Synthetica How's that?

Comment: Better. Much better. (It was showing up in my review cue as a low quality answer)

Answer (score 1):

## Java: 173

```java
public class R{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        int i=0,p=0;
        for(String s:a){
            int j=new Integer(s);
            i=i==0?j:i;
            while(++i<j)
            if(i%2==1)
                System.out.print((p++==0?"":",")+i);
        }
    }
}

//Compressed:
public class R{public static void main(String[]a){
int i=0,p=0;for(String s:a){int j=new Integer(s);i=i==0?j:i;
while(++i<j)if(i%2==1)System.out.print((p++==0?"":",")+i);}}}
```

To run:

```
java R 5 15 18 21 26
```

Produces:

```
7,9,11,13,17,19,23,25
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell - 59

This creates an array of integers bounded by the max and min values in the array of arguments and sends it through the pipeline. It then passes through the numbers that are odd and not in the array of arguments.

```
$x=$args|sort;($x[0]..$x[-1]|?{$_%2-and$_-notin$x})-join','
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 137 chars and almost no spaces

```
import Data.List
main=let n=(map read(words$s)::[Int])in putStr$intercalate","$map show$(filter(\x->x`mod`2==1)[minimum n..maximum n])\\n
```

I love how Haskell doesn't give one crap about spaces.

Put the string in a function `s`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <strike>60</strike> 50 bytes (<strike>55</strike> 47 chars)

HT to JoKing for shrinking it down a substantial number of bytes (mainly via the odd number generation and rearranging to kill some parentheses)

```perl6
{join ',',keys (.min..^.max X+|1)∖$_}o+«*.words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzorPzNPQV1HXSc7tbJYQUMvNzNPTy9OLzexQiFCu8ZQ81HHNJX42nztQ6u19Mrzi1KK/1tzcRUnViqkaSiZKJgpWCgYGippWsOEjBQMgaJAgf8A)

Original answer:

```perl6
(+«*.words).&{(.min+|1,*+2…*>.max-2)∖$_}.keys.join(',')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0P70GotvfL8opRiTT21ag293Mw87RpDHS1to0cNy7Ts9HITK3SNNB91TFOJr9XLTq0s1svKz8zTUNdR1/xvzcVVnFipkKahZKJgpmChYGiopGkNEzJSMASKAgX@AwA)

Here's the explanation for it:

```perl6
(+«*.words)                                             # numberize each word in input (*) 
           .&{                         }                # pass them to an inline method to
                                    ∖                   #   find the set difference of
              (       ,*+2…        )                    #     all odd numbers from
               .min+|1                                  #       1st (bitwise OR 1) to
                           *>.max-2                     #       last (first odd > max-2) 
                                     $_                 #     and the original number set
                                        .keys.join(',') # print final values (.keys is
                                                        #     needed for quirk with Set)
```

If the output were just spaces, could use `.Str`instead of `.keys.join(',')`, but directly using `.join` on Set grabs the internal Bool values.  I'm legitimately surprised there wasn't anything much smaller, but the input/output requirements really killed options

Comment: @JoKing bravo, I really need to get better about using `o`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>20</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#DZÅÉsWL«K',ý
```

Matching the specs exactly.. Input as space-delimited string, output as comma-separated string, or a blank line if no odd integers are found.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f2SXqcOvhzuJwn0OrvdV1Du/9/99IwdBUwUzB0BAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W6aKupHd4h72SwqO2SQpK9v@VXaIOtx7uLA73ObTaW13n8N7/YAU6/6OVTBTMFCwUDA2UdBSUTBUMgchCwchQwcgMJGAEEgCzgCIGENpYwVTBXMESzLEE8oxMFAzNgWKGhkqxAA).

**With flexible/reasonable I/O rules this would be 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):**

```
ZÅÉsWL«K
```

Input as list, output `[]` if no odd integers are found.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6nDr4c7icJ9Dq73//4820jE01THTMTSMBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeXiCvZLCo7ZJCkr2/6MOtx7uLA73ObTa@7/O/@hoEx0zHQsdQ4NYHYVoUx1DILLQMTLUMTIDCRiBBMAsoIgBhDbWMdUx17EEcyyBPCMTHUNzoJihYWwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
#               # Split the (implicit) input-string on spaces
 D              # Duplicate this list
  Z             # Get the maximum (without popping the list itself)
   ÅÉ           # Create a list of all positive odd integers in the range [1, max]
     s          # Swap so the input-list is at the top of the stack again
      W         # Get the minimum (without popping the list itself)
       L        # Create a list in the range [1, min]
        «       # Merge it with the input-list
         K      # Remove all values in this list from the odd list we created earlier
          ',ý  '# Join the result by ","
                # (and output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 73

```
a=$*.map &:to_i;$><<(a.min..a.max).select{|n|n%2>0&&!a.index(n)}.join(?,)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <s>88</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>68</s> <s>63</s> 60 chars

```
@x=@ARGV; # Input doesn't count
sort{$a<=>$b}$x;say join",",grep{$_%2&"@x"!~$_}$x[0]..$x[-1]
```

This can be tested on console as:

```
perl -E '@x=@ARGV;sort{$a<=>$b}$x;say join",",grep{$_%2&"@x"!~$_}$x[0]..$x[-1]' 1 20
```

It outputs the same results as the example, and new line if there are no odd numbers missing.

Comment: This is not correct. First with parameters `1 13` 3 will not be printed (because it matches parameters). Second I don't know such sort in place idiom, at least it doesn't work for on my perl version.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 59 chars:

```
b=range(a<-scan());d=b[1]:b[2];cat(d[!d%in%a&d%%2],sep=",")
```

Expanded a little:

```
a=scan() #Takes serie of integers as input
b=range(a) #Takes min and max
d=b[1]:b[2] #Creates sequence from min to max
cat(d[!d%in%a & d%%2], #Keep only those that are not in input and are odd
    sep=",") #Print them comma-separated
```

Usage:

```
> b=range(a<-scan());d=b[1]:b[2];cat(d[!d%in%a&d%%2],sep=",")
1: 2 15 6
4: 
Read 3 items
3,5,7,9,11,13
> b=range(a<-scan());d=b[1]:b[2];cat(d[!d%in%a&d%%2],sep=",")
1: 5 15 18 21 26
6: 
Read 5 items
7,9,11,13,17,19,23,25
> b=range(a<-scan());d=b[1]:b[2];cat(d[!d%in%a&d%%2],sep=",")
1: 1 3 5 7 9
6: 
Read 5 items
>
```

Answer (score 0):

**VB.net** (154c)

```
Dim a = From w In i.Split(" "c) Select Int32.Parse(w)
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",(From n In Range(a.Min,a.Max-a.Min)
                                   Where n Mod 2 = 1).Except(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 105 (168 with variable+comment)

This code splits the string into 'words', reads the words as integers, and takes all of the odd numbers in the list-difference between the range of the numbers (all integers between the smallest and the largest values) and the list of numbers itself. I then convert it to a string, remove the brackets from the conversion of a list to a string, and print the line.

```
import Data.List
s="1 4 9 12 8 20" -- not counted, in accordance with the rules
main=putStrLn$show[y|let x=(map read).words$s,y<-[minimum x..maximum x]\\x,odd y]\\"[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

### [TinyMUSH](http://www.tinymush.net/index.php/Main_Page), 129

```
&_ me=ifelse(or(eq(words(%0),1),eq(strlen(setr(0,istrue(ldiff(lnum(lmin(%0),lmax(%0)),%0,),mod(##,2),,\\\,))),0)),%r,%q0)
\u(_,X)
```

Replace the "X" in the u() function with the list of whole numbers.  The output is just a carriage return when there is one list item or a lack of odds to output.  Otherwise, the code constructs a list of integers starting from the lowest to the highest in the input.  The code then uses ldiff() to remove from that new list anything that appeared in the input.  Then evens are filtered out with mod(), and the list gets "," as the new delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 - 66

66 characters including 3 for command line options

```
#!perl -lpa
%F=@F=sort{$a<=>$b}@F,@F;$_=join',',grep$_&!$F{$_},"@F"..pop@F
```

Takes multiple lines of data on the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 89

Five less characters and better typing thanks to WallyWest.

```
s='5 15 18 21 26' // not counted
s=s.split(" ");o="";for(i=0;j=+s[i++];)for(;++j<+s[i];)o+=0!=j%2?(o?",":"")+j:"";alert(o)
```

Originally 94 chars.

```
s='5 15 18 21 26' // not counted
s=s.split(' '),o='',i=0;while(j=s[i++])for(j*=1;++j<s[i]*1;)o+=j%2!=0?(o?',':'')+j:'';alert(o)
```

Comment: You could bring it down to 89 by changing the `while` loop to a `for` loop, as well as tidying up the logic and typing of `j`: `s=s.split(" ");o="";for(i=0;j=+s[i++];)for(;++j<+s[i];)o+=0!=j%2?(o?",":"")+j:"";alert(o)`

Answer (score 0):

## Burlesque, 41

```
ln{wdrie!r@{2.%}f[}]m{{Jrij',==$$}f[}m[uN
```

The bloated length is mostly due to mostly formatting the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Haskell <s>104</s> 96 Bytes**

```
import Data.List
l=sort.map read.words
f k=putStr$show[x|x<-[l k!!0..last$l k]\\l k,odd x]\\"[]"
```

A 136 byte version using only predule

```
l=map read.words
c x=foldl1 x.l        
f k=putStr$[z|z<-show[x|x<-[c min k..c max k],x`notElem`l k,odd x], z`notElem`"[]"]
```

Details

```
    --words              |Take a string and break into list (implicit application since f=words is the same as f x = words x)
    --map read           |Convert all the words to a number (the type is inferred at run time based on input)

    l=sort.map read.words

    --[l k!!0..last$l k] |Generate sequence of all numbers from lowest to highest, 
    --\\l k              |Remove any numbers in list l
    --odd x              |Only return odd. 
    --show               |Convert to a string
    --\\"[]"             |Remove the [] characters from the string 
    --putSTr             |Finally, put the string to the terminal. 

    f k=putStr$[z|z<-show[x|x<-[l k!!0..last$l k]\\l k,odd x]]\\"[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 71 bytes

```php
<?=join(array_diff(range(min($a=explode(' ',$i))|1,max($a),2),$a),',');
```

Input as predefined variable `$i`, per spec.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BC4JAEIXv@yseIewu7CEtrTDrFHQI8h4hi665UbmsHozqt9tKBgPz5pvHmzGV6ddbUxlCvFY1bYMEJwLQOSIs4U@pGKYQvqslAh9B9EPBgEbt6PSvZgixwIqSc0xIWVsl84phDJcNPA2Ol/OqvKrRtDYzsnAGLYZALjBJNsAkxnbjPkuutX4waa18ZoUuS2bl46LY3UFPJqozt7pQjIIKT3P@9sVddm7DRcDF0KigPO7HY@k@zXbHQ0w@/Rc)

**Ungolfed / explanation:**

```php
// input is from predefined variable $i
$i = '4 6 8 10';

// split space-delimited string from input into array
$a = explode( ' ', $i );

// create an array of odd numbers starting with the lowest odd number from the input
// ex: [4, 6, 8, 10] => [5, 7, 9]
//     [3, 4, 6, 7]  => [3, 5, 7]
$o = range( min( $a ) | 1, max( $a ), 2 );

// remove any numbers in the input array from the array of odds
// ex: remove [3, 4, 6, 7] from [3, 5, 7] => [ 5 ]
$b = array_diff( $a, $o );

// output array as comma-delimited string
echo join( ',', $b );
```

Or [**74 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Kz8zTyOxqCixMj4lMy1NoygxLz1VIxcoqFJim1pRkJOfkqqhrqCuo5JYlJ6nqVljqJObWAGU1NQx0tQBUeo66prW//@bKhgCkYWCkaGCkdm//IKSzPy84v@6bgA) with input from `STDIN`, [**63 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/rTQvuSQzP09DJVOzuii1pLQoTyGxqCixMj4lMy1NoygxLz1VIzcTLF9jqJObWAFi6Rhp6gAp69r/1lypyRn5Cln5QCUK6jrqOgoqaRoK0aY6CoYgbKGjYGQIxGaxCpoKmtb/AQ) with [flexible I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 89 bytes

```
Complement[Range[Min@#~Floor~2+1,Max@#,2],#]~StringRiffle~","&@*ToExpression@*StringSplit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpPC4IwHIa/yo8JHWyQW1l2CAZRNyG0m3gYsdlgf0R3EKJ99aUJLzwPD6/h/i0M9@rFo4RLvDrTa2GE9U3FbSeaUlmWhLt2bgh0S3DJJ5Zg2uKkDbUflO0qJaUWAWG0YenT3aZ@EOOonGXpeqh7rXx8zOpZKmHH4IMOcIQCSIYwoBzIvAIoAXpcAl3C3@aSrdxDDic4o2/8AQ)

This script is a [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) of three functions, acting from right to left on the input string:

1. [`StringSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) splits the input string into a list of substrings separated by whitespace.
2. [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) then converts this list of substrings into a list of numbers.
3. The actual work is done in the function

   ```
   StringRiffle[Complement[Range[Floor[Min[#], 2] + 1, Max[#], 2], #], ","] &
   ```

   - `Range[Floor[Min[#], 2] + 1, Max[#], 2]` is the list of odd numbers spanning from the smallest to the largest in the supplied list of numbers.
   - With [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) we eliminate those odd numbers that are already present in the supplied list of numbers.
   - What is left is then recomposed into a comma-separated string with [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html).

A more flexible I/O format would reduce this solution to [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8oMS89Ndo3M89Buc4tJz@/qM5I21DHN7HCQVnHKLbOOT@3ICc1NzWvpE5Z7X9AUWZeiYNWmoK@g0J1tYmOmY6FjqFBrY5CtamOIRBZ6BgZ6hiZgQSMQAJgFlDEAEIb65jqmOtY1tb@BwA).

Answer (score -1):

## Javascript

```
function a(e){e=e.split(" ");var t=[];for(i=1;i<e.length*2;i+=2){if(e.join(",").indexOf(i)>-1){}else{t.push(i)}}return t.join(",")}
```

Ungolfed

```
function missingOdd(str) {
    str = str.split(' ');
    var out = [];
    for (i=1; i < str.length * 2; i+=2) {
        if (str.join(',').indexOf(i) > -1) {}else{
            out.push(i);
        }
    }
    return out.join(',');
}
```

Comment: If I give the input `4 6 8 10`, it outputs `3,5,7`. It's wrong output since between `4` & `10`, there is no `3`.